# Error while creating a bean : unsatisfied dependency expressed

Tags: java, spring-mvc

**@Controller**

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass {
    @Autowired
    ServiceClass serviceClass;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getAll(Model model) {
        System.out.println(serviceClass.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("contents", serviceClass.getAll());
        return "NewFile";
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RepositiryClass {

    List<Domain> get();
}
```

**RepoImpl**

```
public class RepoImpl implements RepositiryClass {

    @Override
    public List<Domain> get() {
        List<Domain> dList = new ArrayList<>();
        Domain one = new Domain("testOne", "testTwo");
        Domain two = new Domain("testTwo", "TestOne");
        Domain three = new Domain("three", "three");

        dList.add(one);
        dList.add(two);
        dList.add(three);

        return dList;
    }
```

**@Service**

```
@Service
public interface ServiceClass {

    List<Domain> getAll();
}
```

**ServiceClassImpl**

```
public class ServiceClassImpl implements ServiceClass {

    @Autowired
    RepositiryClass repositriyClass;

    @Override
    public List<Domain> getAll() {

        return repositriyClass.get();
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceClass': No qualifying bean of type [com.controller.domain.service.ServiceClass] found for dependency [com.controller.domain.service.ServiceClass]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.controller.domain.service.ServiceClass] found for dependency [com.controller.domain.service.ServiceClass]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

**root cause**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceClassImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositriyClass': No qualifying bean of type [com.controller.domain.repo.RepositiryClass] found for dependency [com.controller.domain.repo.RepositiryClass]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.controller.domain.repo.RepositiryClass] found for dependency [com.controller.domain.repo.RepositiryClass]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

**package declaration**

[image]

After Searching various forms, I am still not able to solve that
Why I am getting this error as I have everyting implemented and still not sure why I'm getting this error and how to solve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `@Service` Annotation to `ServiceClassImpl`. Not to the Interface.

```
@Service
public class ServiceClassImpl implements ServiceClass {

    @Autowired
    RepositiryClass repositriyClass;

    @Override
    public List<Domain> getAll() {

        return repositriyClass.get();
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ServiceClass {

    List<Domain> getAll();
}
```

also add the `@Repository` Annotation to the Repository implementation:

```
@Repository
public class RepoImpl implements RepositiryClass {

    @Override
    public List<Domain> get() {
        List<Domain> dList = new ArrayList<>();
        Domain one = new Domain("testOne", "testTwo");
        Domain two = new Domain("testTwo", "TestOne");
        Domain three = new Domain("three", "three");

        dList.add(one);
        dList.add(two);
        dList.add(three);

        return dList;
    }
}
```

Not to the interface:

```
public interface RepositiryClass {

    List<Domain> get();
}
```

Remember: The Annotation always belongs to the implementations of the Interfaces. Not to the Interface itselfs

Comment: but `ServiceClassImpl` is implemented from `ServiceClass ` and for repositiry it works okey

Comment: @HelloWorld But it is also wrong. The Annotation must be on the implementing classes not on the Interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, but implementing at interface provides a wider scope(just a idea, please correct me If am wrong)

Comment: @HelloWorld . The Annotation must be on the implementing classes not on the Interfaces

Comment: I am still getting same exception

Comment: can you Show the package declarations of your classes? And also take a look at the exception. Is it excatly the same?

Comment: I added the snapshot

Comment: @HelloWorld And can you doble check the exception? Also have you cleaned and rebuild your Project?

Comment: yes sir, I cleaned the project workspace,tomcat but still getting exception

Comment: @HelloWorld can you post the exception

Comment: now the `com.controller.domain.repo.RepositiryClass` is the Problem. have you changed it too?

Comment: its working now, actually I was annotating `interface` instead of classes, my bad BTW thanks for the help and for  the time on this post :)